# iterator find - referencing the needle instead of dereferencing the iterating item

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let greater_than_42 = (0..100).find(|x| *x > 42);
    match greater_than_42 {
        Some(x) => println!("{}", x),
        None => println!("no numbers found"),
    }
}
```

If I do this instead:

```
    let greater_than_42 = (0..100).find(|x| x > &42);
```

would it compare memory addresses, instead of values?

Comment: What is so bad about my question? Care to elaborate?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the person may be unhappy that [it was crossposted](http://users.rust-lang.org/t/iterator-find-referencing-the-needle-instead-of-dereferencing-the-iterating-item/764) without any links between them. (Meaning, e.g., someone may waste effort if they don't realise that the question is already answered on the other site.)

Comment: One of the canonical causes for a -1 is “this question does not show any research effort”. I considered this to be a question for which “just try it and observe the results!” is sufficient, though upon reviewing it later I suppose that an incomplete understanding of pointers would make the certainty of the logical conclusion of experimentation (viz. that `&T` comparison is not pointer comparison) not so sure.

Comment: I did test my code, the problem was I couldn't be certain because I could just have been lucky i.e. pointers were arranged in such a manner that the observable effect was the same, but not the semantics. Yet my question is about the underlying semantics, not about blind observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply trying it will demonstrate clearly that this is not the case.

In Rust, raw pointers (`*const T` and `*mut T`) are the only places where memory addresses are significant.

References (`&T` and `&mut T`) are transparent in that manner; if you want to compare the memory addresses (e.g. to see if two immutable references are to the same location, though this is of very limited practical application with Rust’s ownership model) you will need to cast them to raw pointers first.

Comment: Thanks. Of course I've tried it, but it could have been the case that it worked just because I was lucky.